# How to explain these lines of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, indexing, integer

Both `light` and `order` are arrays containing states with the period of time they are displayed.

However I'm not too sure about what Index does or 'sId'. could someone please explain these? The code changes the sequence of a traffic light. The code works however I wanted to know what `lightIndex` does, as when I change it it doesn't work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.light {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.lightRed {
    background-color: red;
}
.lightYellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.lightGreen {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="trafficLight">
    <div>Click to Start and Stop</div>
    <div class="light" id="Red"></div>
    <div class="light" id="Yellow"></div>
    <div class="light" id="Green"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="changeState()">Change Lights</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeState()">automatic</button>
<script>
var changeState = (function () {
    var state = 0,
        lights = ["Red", "Yellow", "Green"],
        lightsLength = lights.length,
        order = [
            [7000, "Red"],
            [2000, "Red", "Yellow"],
            [7000, "Green"],
            [2000, "Yellow"]
        ],
        orderLength = order.length,
        lightIndex,
        orderIndex,
        sId;

    return function (stop) {
        if (stop) {
            clearTimeout(sId);
            return;
        }

        var light,
        lampDOM;

        for (lightIndex = 0; lightIndex < lightsLength; lightIndex += 1) {
            light = lights[lightIndex];
            lightDOM = document.getElementById(light);
            if (order[state].indexOf(light) !== -1) {
                lightDOM.classList.add("light" + light);
            } else {
                lightDOM.classList.remove("light" + light);
            }
        }

        sId = setTimeout(changeState, order[state][0]);
        state += 1;
        if (state >= orderLength) {
            state = 0;
        }
    };
}());

document.querySelector('change Lights', 'automatic').addEventListener("click", (function () {
    var state = false;

    return function () {
        changeState(state);
        state = !state;
    };
}()), false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lightIndex` and `sId` are both just variable names created by whoever wrote the code. They don't 'mean' anything inherently -- the creator of the code could have chosen whatever variable names they wanted. However, in your code, both of these variables have uses that are fairly self-evident from their names.

`lightIndex` is an integer (between 0 and 2), which is used as an index of the array `lights`, so that the current light (`light`) can access the relevant colour with `light = lights[lightIndex];`. Presumably `lights` is set up like `var lights = ['green', 'orange', 'red']`. So, for example, `light = lights[lightIndex]` becomes `light = lights[1]`, making `light` become equivalent to `orange`.

`sId` is a time-delayed function (`setTimeout(changeState, order[state][0]);`). `setTimeout()` takes two parameters -- a function to execute, and a time delay in milliseconds. In this example, `order[state][0]` will be equivalent to something like `1000` (one second), and `changeState()` is the function to execute. Essentially, every one second, change the state of the light (to a different colour).

I don't know why you'd try to *change* `lightIndex`, but if you want to reverse the direction of the lights changing, you need to reverse the `for` loop:

```
for (lightIndex = 0; lightIndex < lightsLength; lightIndex += 1) {
```

Becomes:

```
for (lightIndex = lightsLength; lightIndex > 0; lightIndex -= 1) {
```

If you want to change the speed, you need to change `order[state][0]`. As you don't show the `order` variable's code, you'll need to work out how to change that yourself.

Hope this helps!